# Xamarin UWP Windows 10 phone emulator

Tags: windows, forms, mobile

I am working on a Xamarin forms solution. I am primarily targeting Android, IOS and Windows 10. I do not see an option to run the UWP project on a windows phone emulator. The options I get are Simulator, emulator, local machine, remote machine and device which run windows 10 in tablet configuration. I can confirm that I have windows 10 phone emulators installed. I can see that it also has a windows phone 8.1 project which curiously run a Windows phone 10 emulator. How do I get the UWP project deployed and debug on a windows 10 phone emulator please ?

Comment: Does "Emulator" option not open a phone emulator? On my end I ahve a few Win 10 phone emulators and I don't recall ever having installed them, but there is a "Download new emulator" option. Do you have that option? If so can you try it? It takes me to a web page to download updated Windows SDK: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Comment: I tried to download emulators and Visual studio asked me to restart before downloading the emulators and now I have the phone emulators working. Thanks :-).